# Flash Packages and Inheritance

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Why human cannot find God in this structure ?

```
c:\myproject\src\
    main.as
    human.as
    com\god\
        God.as
        IGod.as
```

human.as :

```
import com.*;
public class human extend God implements IGod {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because god is hiding in his own folder, and humans can only see files (ActionScript does not import recursively). If you import this way:

```
import com.god.*
public class human extend God implements IGod {
    ...
}
```

it should work.

Comment: also note that the package statement needs to be updated. package com.god {

Answer (score 1):

"*" means all classes in that package, not all classes of all sub-packages of that package.

Try

```
import com.god.*;
```

Instead.